# Why are Keras Conv1D weights not changed during training?

Tags: python, keras

I initialise my network with only one Convolutional layer (8 filters with length 10).

```py
# Initialize Convolutional Neural Network
cnn = Sequential()
conv = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=10, strides=1, padding="same", input_shape=(train.values.shape[1]-1, 1))
cnn.add(conv)
cnn.add(Activation("relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding="same"))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
cnn.summary()
```

I take the weights once before and once after the training and plot them with a function I wrote.

```py
w1 = conv.get_weights()[0][:, 0, :]
print(w1[:,0])
plot_weights(w1)

# Fit CNN
y = to_categorical(train.values[:, -1])
X_cnn = np.expand_dims(train.values[:, :-1], axis=2)
start = time.time()
cnn.fit(X_cnn, y, verbose=1, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.2, epochs=20)
end = time.time()

w2 = conv.get_weights()[0][:, 0, :]
print(w2[:,0])
plot_weights(w2)
```

Function to plot the weights:

```py
def plot_weights(w):
    w_min = w.min()
    w_max = w.max()
    n = w.shape[0]
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1)
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
        im = ax.imshow(w[:, i].reshape(1, n), vmin=w_min, vmax=w_max, interpolation="nearest",
                       cmap="gray")  # Display weights as image
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)  # Hide y ticks
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', length=0)  # Set length of y ticks to 0

    fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())
    plt.show(block=False)

    return
```

The output looks like this:

[Before training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux9fk.png)

[After training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll5vK.png)

When i print the first filter before and after training, you can also see that it is the exact same numbers (not even slightly changed).

```
>>>[-0.20076838  0.03835052 -0.04454999 -0.20220913  0.24402907  0.03407234
 -0.09768075  0.16887552  0.12767741  0.00756356]
>>>[-0.20076838  0.03835052 -0.04454999 -0.20220913  0.24402907  0.03407234
 -0.09768075  0.16887552  0.12767741  0.00756356]
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? The network is clearly learning something, since i get an accuracy of nearly 100%.

--ga97dil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to access the model itself that is being trained, i.e. `cnn` rather than the definition you use to initialise the layer i.e. `conv`.

Try `cnn.layers[0].get_weights()[:, 0, :]` instead of `conv.get_weights()[0][:, 0, :]`.